# How can I get the current route's name in vue.js?

Tags: html, templates, if-statement, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to use the current `route's` name in a `v-if` statement in a a template. I have read that there is a complicated 3rd party way, but I want something better.

```
<template v-if="$this.routes.getName() == '/customers'">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you register the route with a name then it's too simple

Your route

```
{
 name: 'Foo',
 path: '/foo'
 component: 'Foo.vue'
}
```

Then it's just

```
this.$route.name
```

And it will return `Foo`

You can compare with name, however if you want to compare with path then

```
this.$route.path // it will return exact path after domain i.e. www.google.com/foo
if(this.$route.path === '/foo') {
  console.log('I am on foo route')
}
```

**Try loggin your route object** and explore what else you have

```
console.log(this.$route)
```